# Guardar valor de um select e exibir

Tags: java, html, aplicação-web, select

Estou desenvolvendo um CRUD de um sistema web. No cadastro do funcionario utilizo dois elementos select para exibir as opçoes, ao cadastrar funcionar tudo ok, as informaçoes vao para o banco. O problema é ao clicar em editar e trazer essas informaçoes do select, o select ta tela de editar vem com o valor inicial do select; exemplo: no cadastro coloquei que sou suporte, ao editar o campo select esta administrador e nao o correto, suporte. Alguem pode me ajudar a trazer a informaçao correta desses selects.

Tela de cadastro onde coloque as opções SUPERVISOR E SUPORTE
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na tela de editar, os campos aparecem como administrador.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu form de funcionarios

```
<div class="row">
<form action="@{funcionarios.salvarFuncionarios}" method="post">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="hidden" name="funcionario.id" value="${f?.id}" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nome completo:</label> <input type="text"
                name="funcionario.nome" class="form-control"
                value="${flash['funcionario.nome'] ? flash['funcionario.nome'] : f?.nome}">
            <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'funcionario.nome' /}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email:</label> <input type="text" name="funcionario.email"
                class="form-control"
                value="${flash['funcionario.email'] ? flash['funcionario.email'] : f?.email}">
            <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'funcionario.email' /}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Função:</label> <select name="funcionario.funcao"
                class="form-control"
                value="${flash['funcionario.funcao'] ? flash['funcionario.funcao'] : f?.funcao}">
                <option>Administrador</option>
                <option>Suporte</option>
                <option>Supervisor</option>
            </select> <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'funcionario.funcao' /}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nível de acesso:</label> <select
                name="funcionario.nivelAcesso" class="form-control"
                value="${flash['funcionario.nivelAcesso'] ? flash['funcionario.nivelAcesso'] : f?.nivelAcesso}">
                <option>Administrador</option>
                <option>Suporte</option>
            </select> <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'funcionario.nivelAcesso'
                /}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    #{if f}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nome de usuário:</label> <input id="loginUsuario" type="text" placeholder="Mínimo 5 caracteres"
                name="funcionario.login" class="form-control" disabled="disabled"
                value="${flash['funcionario.login'] ? flash['funcionario.login'] : f?.login}">
            <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'funcionario.login' /}</span>
        </div>
        #{/if}
        #{ifnot f}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nome de usuário:</label> <input id="loginUsuario" type="text" placeholder="Mínimo 5 caracteres"
                name="funcionario.login" class="form-control"
                value="${flash['funcionario.login'] ? flash['funcionario.login'] : f?.login}">
            <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'funcionario.login' /}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Senha:</label> <input type="password" placeholder="Mínimo 6 caracteres"
                name="funcionario.senha" class="form-control"
                value="${flash['funcionario.senha'] ? flash['funcionario.senha'] : f?.senha}">
            <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'funcionario.senha' /}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Confirmar senha:</label> <input type="password" name="senha"
                class="form-control"> <span class="alert-danger">#{error
                'senha' /}</span>
        </div>
        #{/ifnot}
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger"
            onclick="window.location.href='/funcionarios/listagemFuncionarios';">
            Cancelar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você esta apenas listando os dados do select, e não 
define qual será o item selecionado do `<option>` usando o `selected`, exemplo:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

1- sugiro criar um **array** com `[Administrador,Suporte,Supervisor]`

2- fazer um **foreach** adicionando cada item em um `<option>`, caso o item atual seja igual ao item `flash['funcionario.funcao']` *(valor anteriormente selecionado)*

Desculpe não poder ajudar com a sintaxe, espero ter ajudado.